# Performance Measurement of Angular Application?

Tags: angular

I've created an angular application. I would like to measure the performance of my angular component methods. Like if we have getDetails() in angular component then tool should display like it's taking this amount of time and you can do something to fix it. Similarly for events as well.

I tried boomerangjs using rt plugin to find it out (https://akamai.github.io/boomerang/tutorial-building.html) but it's giving only pageload details.

I tried navigation and Resource apis as well but not luck. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use chrome dev tools

```
Yourwebpage--->inspect ----->network
```

There is best tool introduce `Augury` from angular

[original sourse link](https://augury.rangle.io/)

> What is Augury Augury is the most used Developer Tool extension for
>   debugging and profiling Angular applications inside the Google Chrome
>   and Mozilla Firefox browsers.
>
> Why Use Augury? Augury helps Angular developers visualize the
>   application through component trees, and visual debugging tools.
>   Developers get immediate insight into their application structure,
>   change detection and performance characteristics.

Comment: due to restriction I can't install augury. and I don't have to user Chrome developer tool. Because it don't show which method is taking time. it display how much time js/css files are taking